# How to check CSRF token serverside if i am not using session cookies?

Tags: php, jquery, session, cookies, csrf

In our current project, we implement persistent sessions by using cookies. When the user logs in a session hash is generated and sent via a user cookie. On every page load that is checked with the corresponding session entry in the database and the user is authenticated.

In the past if i had to do csrf token check, i would normally have assined a session variable for the particualar session. And on every subsequent ajax calls i would have matched the csrf token sent as a custom header in the ajax request, with the session variable.

However for the present project i cannot find a proper way to do this. A secure hash can be created and can be added as a custom header or as a hidden input field or even as a parameter in the ajax request. But how do i validate it on the client side ?

For the time being i am doing something like `str_rot13(base64_encode(some_secret_key))` and sending it as the csrf token.

Then on the server side i am doing the reverse, obtaining the secret_key and matching it with the secret key that i have configured for my app. This however doesn't seem at all secure to me. I have thought of using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32) , openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16) etc..` But again, thats a hash i would be generating. How would I validate it on the server side?!

What can be some best practices that i can adopt, given the user authentication mechanism that i am following?

Comment: The subject and content of the question contradict each other. You seem to be using sessions. So why can't you store a CSRF token in there?

Comment: I am not using the $_SESSION variable like i said above.

Comment: A cookie is (technically) a session; PHP parlance just confuses the matter. You should store an *encrypted* version of the CSRF token in the cookie, and then validate the copy in the form against it on each POST (+ PUT|DELETE) request. If possible, use a crypto library that can perform a constant time comparison to avoid leaking any internal state. Use URL-safe base64 encoded values that leverage a crytographically strong PRNG (open_ssl_random_... looks good).

Comment: Well, i went back to the encrypted token architecture. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Encrypted_Token_Pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSRF token without cookies in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679327/csrf-token-without-cookies-in-php)