# CSRF token without cookies in PHP

Tags: php, security, session, cookies, csrf

I am looking for a way to add a CSRF token to an application I'm making. The caveat is, the application does not currently use cookies or sessions.

I would love to find a way to introduce a CSRF token without having to:

1. Introduce state in my application.
2. Use session or cookie (`$_SESSION` / `$_COOKIE`) storage

Is this at all a possibility, or am I stuck creating new state in my application.

Comment: How would you know if the token is good without a concept of server side storage?

Comment: CSRF tokens kind of *are* state-validation. "Stateless CSRF token" is nonsensical.

Comment: Any solution you come up with that doesn't use cookies or server-side state is probably going to defeat the purpose of CSRF tokens

Comment: Hi guys... if any of you can expand a bit on your comment, I would be happy to take it as an answer.

Comment: Using sessions is trivial in PHP. Why the reluctance to use it?

Comment: Deleted my answer. Yes, you _can_ - JWT, lock to timeout/IP/whatever. But - why _would_ you? All forms are public anyway w/o state. CSRF prevents pretending to be some other user - you have no users, no state. Only reason I've thought of yet is a comment form storing which IP said what, in which case, JWT as above.

Comment: @Iiridayn you know, I have absolutely no idea what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it's not going to be very secure.

Here's an example **BUT DO NOT USE THIS, IT IS PROBABLY A BAD IDEA**:

```
// Do this somewhere
define('CSRF_SALT', '4dedMj4CWgBMNhRsoTpJlokwB5wTz7UsmF8Mq4uzFIbv');

$token = base64_encode(
    hash_hmac(
        'sha256', 
        date('Ymd') . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CSRF_SALT,
        true
    )
);

if (\hash_equals($_POST['security_token'], $token)) {
    // Form passes validation
}
```

The downside is that these tokens are inherently reusable, so if one leaks an attacker can simply reuse (or recalculate) it. You can also try adding the form action="" value in the hash calculation.

```
function getToken($action)
{
    return base64_encode(
        hash_hmac(
            'sha256', 
            hash_hmac(
                'sha256',
                date('Ymd') . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                hash('sha256', $action, true),
                true
            ),
            CSRF_SALT,
            true
        )
    );
}

echo "<form action='register.php' method='post'>\n";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='security_token' value='".getToken('register.php')."' />\n";
// ...
```

What's your anathema for sessions anyway?

Comment: The reason I don't like sessions is because it requires server-side storage. I work on an open source library, so that means there's more stuff to document, and ideally I also need to provide a way to make it work on multiple load-balanced servers.

Comment: I realize memcache-backed session storage can help with that... but the less I have to explain, the better. Great answer, but in the end I have decided to just use a cookie anyway (but no sessions).

Comment: https://resonantcore.net/blog/2015/02/modern-defense-against-csrf-attacks - If you use composer, you can use resonantcore/anti-csrf as a dependency.

Comment: That library uses sessions. Not all that helpful. It's a pretty simply thing to solve anyway with just cookies, so it doesn't make that much sense to add a new dependency for it.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt Using this JWT library to encrypt client-side session state might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lightweight db and store a token, along with the ip adres, user agent, expiry time and requested url or you can try using a database and session storage to store a key with which tokens are created. E.g.

```
$post = array();
If (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    If (isset($_POST['csrftoken']) && isset($_SESSION['csrfkey'])) {
        // check if csrftoken exists in db and fetch the row
        $hash = hash('sha256', $row['String'] . $_SESSION['csrfKey']);
        // delete the db record
        If ($hash === $_POST['csrfToken']) {
           $post = (array) $_POST;
           // check if expiry time has not passed
           // check requested url 
           // check user agent and ip adres
        }
    }
    $_REQUEST = null;
    $_POST = null;
}

If (!isset($_SESSION['csrfKey'])) {
    $_SESSION['csrfKey'] = uniqid('key_', true);
}
$string = uniqid('token_', true);
$token = hash('sha256', $string . $_SESSION['csrfKey']);
// save token and string along with expirytime in db
echo "<input type='hidden' name='csrftoken' value='" . $token . "' />";
```

Answer (score -2):

CSRF protection works by comparing a token embedded in a page with a token associated with the browser that the page was sent to.

It is absolutely impossible to do this without introducing state.

Comment: The answer sounds very confident ("absolutely impossible"), and is "absolutely" wrong. I do not want it to seem to be a potentially correct answer to someone who knows less about this area than I do.

Comment: The above was in response to a now deleted comment by @Evert who had been wondering why this question had been previously downvoted.